# jquery onchange event handler ignore if certain controls clicked

Tags: jquery, event-handling

I want a textbox's onchange event NOT executed if it was caused by the user clicking a certain element.

What's a good way to do this?

Edit:

The user clicks away from a textbox. 
The textbox  looses focus and the ONCHANGE event is fired.
So far so good.
I just want it not to fire if the user clicked the Cancel button, for instance.

This is important because the ONCHANGE code fires an expensive ajax call to the database.

Comment: What elements do you have that cause a textbox to change that involve clicking. What have you tried? Do you have a JSFiddle?

Comment: user clicks on an element thus causing a textbox to loose focus.

Comment: You probably can't prevent that. Just put an if clause in there to check the focus of the textbox? If notHasFocus don't run your change event.